# Force Tkinter widget to lose its focus

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, focus

I'm not able to do this:

```
button = ttk.Button(frame , state = DISABLED , command = lambda: a_function())

def control_s(event):
    if button.instate(["!disabled"]):
        button.focus_get()
        a_function()
root.bind("<Control-s>" , lambda event: control_s(event))
```

When I type "Control+s" I want to lose immediately a spinbox focus in order to validate first the data and then put the focus on the button to store the data correctly in a DDBB.

Any ideas please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this help `frame.bind` instead of `root.bind`?

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried this before. With all my related frames

Comment: How about this one? `frame.bind("<Control-s>", control_s)` instead of `root.bind`.

Comment: Buuuffff.... Is not working. I'm clompletly lost. I don't know why this simple code doesn't work

Comment: Are you using py charm, pytorch or MACOS, etc?

Comment: Nope...  I'm using VSCode on Windows and Linux. And the result is the same.

Comment: I'm actually sorry. I discontinued VSC to Python. Please edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help

```
button = ttk.Button(frame, state="disabled", command=lambda: a_function())
def control_s(event):
    if button.instate(["!disabled"]):
        button.focus_set()
        a_function()
root.bind("<Control-s>", control_s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Mmmmm... doesn't work. I tried this before. Thank you very much.